# How can I add conditional query string to the URL in MVC 4?

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4, routes

I am having some trouble adding a conditional query string to the URL.

```
if the url == domain/controller/action then 
    do nothing

if the url == domain/controller/action?referenceNumber=xxxx then
    url = domain/controller/action?referenceNumber=xxxx&newParameter=yyyy
```

I have tried to override the `OnActionExecuting` without any luck, and I am not very strong on RouteConfig.

Ideas?

I have tried the following

```
protected override IAsyncResult BeginExecute(RequestContext requestContext, AsyncCallback callback, object state)
{
   var path = requestContext.HttpContext.Request.RawUrl;

   if(myCondition)
   {
      requestContext.HttpContext.RewritePath(string.Format("{0}&newParameter={1}", path, getNewParameter()); 
   }

   return base.BeginExecute(requestContext, callback, state);
}
```

this would update the `HttpContext.Request.Url` but would not reflect the URL in the browser.

How to overcome this challenge? Any clue?

Comment: Where is this code executing, if it's in the view there's a better way.  If it's in the controller it doesn't make sense because MVC is all about routing.  Please let us know where the code is running

Comment: @JohnPeters thank you for your quick response. It is in the controller level. as i mentioned earlier I am not so strong at Routing, i don't know how to resolve this issue

Comment: What you are showing is a typical Get Post workflow, you simply need to have two action methods with same name, one only for GETs requests the other only for POSTs.  The Post method would either accept a string or if you look into Viewmodels a property contained within that Viewodel.  I personally find View Models much easier to work with.  Bottom line you have to learn about MVC Post patterns.

Comment: @JohnPeters thank you once again for your suggestion. I have done it through the action (Get) `public ActionResult Action(string referenceNumber, string newParameter){...}` (Post) `public ActionResult Action(Object myObject, string newParameter){...}` its working fine. I wish there was an easier way other than adding the new parameter to all the actions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was been able to resolve the issue by using the following...

GET Method

```
public ActionResult Action(string referenceNumber, string newParameter){...}
```

POST Method

```
public ActionResult Action(Object myObject, string newParameter){...}
```

the result was browser is showing

> domain/controller/action?referenceNumber=xxxx&newParameter=yyyy